# AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'addMapLayer'

Tags: python, pyqgis, ubuntu

I am running the following script on Ubuntu terminal to create a polygon from points in a csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from qgis.core import *
     
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.initQgis()

# Put your pyqgis code here:
uri = "file:////home/aka000/site4/PyQGIS/Tailings_Pond_1A.csv?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Lat", "Long","epsg:4326")

#Make a vector layer
eq_layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"eq-data","delimitedtext")

#Check if layer is valid
if not eq_layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer not loaded")

#Add CSV data    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)

points = [QgsPointXY(f['long'], f['lat']) for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()]
poly = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points]) #Create a polygon geometry

#Create a empty memory layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&index=yes", "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

newfeature = QgsFeature()
newfeature.setGeometry(poly)
provider.addFeature(newfeature)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

# Finally, exitQgis() is called to remove the
# provider and layer registries from memory
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Here is the error I get:

```
File "./test.py", line 23, in <module>
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)
AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'addMapLayer'
```

I wrote the same script in python console in windows and it worked well, but I need to run it on Linux:

```
ri = "file:///C:/Users/katala/Desktop/PyQGIS/Tailings Pond 1A.csv?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Lat", "Long","epsg:4326")

#Make a vector layer
eq_layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"eq-data","delimitedtext")

#Check if layer is valid
if not eq_layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer not loaded")

#Add CSV data    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)

points = [QgsPointXY(f['long'], f['lat']) for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()]
poly = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points]) #Create a polygon geometry

#Create a empty memory layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&index=yes", "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

newfeature = QgsFeature()
newfeature.setGeometry(poly)
provider.addFeature(newfeature)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Answer (score 3):

You get that error because you use QGIS 2. In QGIS 2, `QgsProject` class has no `addMapLayer` method. You should use `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer` instead of `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer`.

A more reasonable solution would be you to use QGIS 3.